# Amazon soap interface using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, soap

Hi i am trying to use soap to get results from amazon, and i havent tried this before so i was trying some sample code. The problem is i get an error.
the code is this:

```
<?php
#Use the NuSOAP php library
//require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$params->AWSAccessKeyId = AMAZON_API_KEY;
$params->Request->SearchIndex = 'Books';
$params->Request->Keywords = 'php5';

$amazon = new SoapClient('http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService       /AWSECommerceService.wsdl');
$result = $amazon->itemSearch($params); 


echo $result;
?>
```

and this is the error i get when i run it. thanx for your time

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [aws:Client.MissingParameter] The request must contain the parameter Signature. in C:\wamp\www\amasearch.php:11 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('itemSearch', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\amasearch.php(11): SoapClient->itemSearch(Object(stdClass)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\amasearch.php on line 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird. The WSDL doesn't have a signature parameter for any type. BUT, I found this in Amazon dev forums. Recommend you to check it out (also, if you develop using amazon services, keep that resource at hand

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=483

Looks like security gates for services are now taller and bigger, mate

EDIT: This question link to some example in C#. Maybe it can help you out [Amazon (AWS) - The request must contain the parameter Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935158/amazon-aws-the-request-must-contain-the-parameter-signature)

And this is an example in AWS forums with PHP https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=149715